# Set focus to an element that only shows up when the parent is focused

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the JSFiddle for this question: https://jsfiddle.net/g92u4deo/0/

In this JSFiddle, what I am trying to achieve is to set the focus on the #small div when its parent #big got focus. i.e. when a user tab to the blue box, the red box gets focus and stay visible.

How do I do this?

Btw, you would see an intentional wait of 500ms in my code like below. This was done to make sure the #small can be visible before the focus was set. Although I don't think this is strictly necessary, I put it there because I think you can't set focus to an invisible element.

```
big.onfocus = function () {
    console.log("Big focused");
  console.log("Active Element: " + document.activeElement.id);
  setTimeout(function () {
    small.focus();
    console.log("Active Element: " + document.activeElement.id);
  }, 500);
}
```

Update: 
I found a solution soon after posting this.

Using `opacity` seems to work, but `display` doesn't.

https://jsfiddle.net/g92u4deo/1/

It would be great to hear about other solution too.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @AGE Updated the question. Sorry for not making it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout demo

```js
var big = document.getElementById("big");
var small = document.getElementById("small");
var log = document.getElementById("log");
big.onfocus = function () {
  big.classList.add('focused');
  small.classList.add('focused');
  small.focus();
  log.innerText = document.activeElement.id;
}
big.onblur = function () {
  if(!small.classList.contains('focused')){
    big.classList.remove('focused');
  }
  log.innerText = document.activeElement.id;
}
small.onfocus = function(){
  log.innerText = document.activeElement.id;
}
small.onblur = function(){
  small.classList.remove('focused');
  big.classList.remove('focused');
  log.innerText = document.activeElement.id;
}
```

```css
#big {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#big.focused {
  background: lightblue;
}
#small {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

#small.focused {
  background: pink;
  display: block;
}
#log{
  clear:both;
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="big" tabindex="1">
  <div id="small" tabindex="-1">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is due to the fact that you can't focus on a hidden element. When you invoke the `.focus()` method on the `#small` element (i.e., `small.focus()`), you are consequently removing the focus from the `#big` element, which means that the selector `#big:focus #small` will no longer select the `#small` element and set the `display` to `block` (since only one element can have focus at a time).

#### Potential Solutions:

As you have already pointed out, the easiest option would be to use the `opacity` property to hide the element rather than the `display` property. In doing so, the element is technically not hidden:

```js
document.getElementById("big").addEventListener('focus', function() {
  document.getElementById("small").focus();
});
```

```css
#big {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#small {
  width: 60px; height: 60px;
  background: pink;
  opacity: 0;
}

#small:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="big" tabindex="0">
  <div id="small" tabindex="-1">Small</div>
</div>
```

However, in some cases you may not be able to change the element's opacity because you don't want it to occupy space. An alternative would be to remove any possible padding/margins/borders and then set the dimensions on the element to `0`. As soon as the element has focus, you would revert that and it would work as expected.

Here is a basic example demonstrating this:

```js
document.getElementById("big").addEventListener('focus', function() {
  document.getElementById("small").focus();
});
```

```css
#big {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#small {
  /* Explicity set everything to 0 initally.. */
  width: 0; height: 0;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  border: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

#small:focus {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: visible;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="big" tabindex="0">
  <div id="small" tabindex="-1">Small</div>
</div>
```

As an alternative, you could also absolutely position the element off the screen initially. In doing so, it will be hidden yet still focusable:

```js
document.getElementById("big").addEventListener('focus', function() {
  document.getElementById("small").focus();
});
```

```css
#big {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#small {
  /* Absolutely position the element off the screen initially */
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

#small:focus {
  position: static;
  top: auto; left: auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="big" tabindex="0">
  <div id="small" tabindex="-1">Small</div>
</div>
```

---

The three potential workarounds above require you to manually set the CSS on the element. If you want this to be handled automatically, you could add a `focusable` class to the element before invoking the `.focus()` method. When the element has focus, simply remove the class.

In doing so, you can still set the element's `display` property to `none` initially.

```js
var big = document.getElementById("big");
var small = document.getElementById("small");

big.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  small.classList.add('focusable');
  small.focus();
});
small.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.classList.remove('focusable');
});
```

```css
#big {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

#small {
  display: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: pink;
}

#small.focusable,
#small:focus {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="big" tabindex="0">
  <div id="small" tabindex="-1">Small</div>
</div>
```